# How to convert headless wordpress href to <Link>

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, headless-cms

Not sure if this is possible but I am using Next.js with the WordPress API aka headless wordpress. I am outputting a Gutenberg area which consists of text and links. The problem with the links is that they aren't done the Next.js way and when you click one you can see in console that it is reloading the whole page instead of linking without refreshing.

So, if I were setting up the links in Next.js I would do

```
  <Link href="/posts/first-post">
    <a>this page!</a>
  </Link>
```

But because I am doing this

```
      <div
        className="content"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(homeData.kidsSectionContent),
        }}
      />
```

I am getting whatever WordPress gives me so `<a href="some-page">click me<a/>`

Comment: Have you tried parsing the HTML you get from WordPress and replacing the `<a>`s?

Comment: @juliomalves, don't know how to do that, I will look it up. But I would also need to somehow distinguish between internal an external links because they should be treated differently I would imagine.

Comment: You can parse the `href` value and determine whether they're internal/external.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works like you want. Because `<Link` is actually JSX code, which is just html-like code which is converted to javascript.

Actually the `<Link ...>` syntax is compiled to something like:

```js
const Link = require("path/to/Link.js");
React.createElement(Link, {props});
```

You are fetching raw html data from an api, and you want that data to be converted to compiled javascript. So it can be hooked into React. Which, as I understand, is maybe possible, but not very usable. Because a simple broken html result, will break your pages.

I think you need to ask yourself why you want to have a single-page behaviour.

However, I think if you can replace your html with reactive syntax, and then parse it with JSX, you can probably get what you want. But it will probably be slow, and could break pages.

Comment: The issue is that the Next.js site in general is really fast. But then when you have internal linking from the API, it slows it down when you click on one of those links because it is refreshing the whole page again and reloading everything and it's not a great experience in comparison.